# Unity Application crashing when loading images

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've written a Unity3D game and installed on Android. The game often, but not always, crashes during an operation to load a collection of image resources used by my game. Specifically the application disappears into the background and when I select it, it then restarts. At the moment I can't figure out what is causing this behaviour, I've examined logcat logs when this happens but I can't find any message telling what has happened.

Has anyone experienced similar behaviour and if so what was the solution? Is there a way of finding out why the game has crashed or increase memory allocated to it in case the game is running out of memory loading the images?

Comment: I suggested a solution below - was it helpful?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, see my reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of images and the compression rate are configurable in the Unity IDE, and can change between platforms. In Unity 5, as a default the max size for an image is 2048 or 4096, which are not fully supported in all devices. I suggest as a first solution to go to the Unity project, select the image assets, scroll down to the setting box for each image, click on the Android tab, check the box marked "override for Android", and change the max size to 1024.

Apply the change, play test to confirm the image is still sharp enough, and re-build the game. I believe this may help you solve the issue.

[image: changing image max size for Android on an image asset]

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I had already configured this setting in the IDE (it's very important for this particular game that the images are a precise size, namely 606 x 480 pixels). I'm not even sure if the behavior I'm seeing indicates that the game is running out of memory.

Comment: If it's something that happens only in the android build, it's sensible to assume that there's a memory issue. I didn't inquire about the device you were using, but perhaps lowering the resolution or increasing the compression even higher and testing it may help narrow it down. If it is the image load memory than it will be a matter of playing with the settings until a good middle ground is found.

Comment: I'll try as you suggest thankyou. I wish there was a way of confirming it's the memory though. As I mentioned in the question, sometimes the game runs okay, makes me wonder why if the game is demanding too much memory.